# Binary image circle fitting

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry

I a new to MATLAB and i am trying to apply circle fitting technique to the following image.

*Image*

[image]

*Expected Output*

[image]

I used the following code with no luck:

```matlab
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(W,[30 65],'ObjectPolarity','bright');
figure,imshow(W);% title('Sobel gradient');
viscircles(centers,radii,'Color','b');
```

*Note that the circle size can vary between picture*

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So close! You just have to adjust the sensitivity a bit. It ranges from 0 to 1, the higher the more circles are found. By default it is 0.85. Also had to adjust the radius a bit:

```
imshow(W) % assuming W is logical
[centers,radii] = imfindcircles(W,[40 60],'ObjectPolarity','bright','Sensitivity',0.925)
viscircles(centers, radii,'EdgeColor','b');
```

I don't think it's possible to find the lower circle without also getting some false positives first - ultimately it's not very round.

[image: resultimage]

Comment: @LeanderMoesigner how can it get the identified circle count?

Comment: With `numel(radii)`

Comment: after changing sensitivity to 0.98 it gives me a very good result. So i think that your answer should be marked as accepted so this will helps others when searching. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried to play a little bit with this image despite not being a good digital images analyst. I found the following approach much more flexible:

```
img = imread('1GBtO.png');
img = im2bw(img);

rp = regionprops('table',img,'Centroid','Eccentricity','EquivDiameter','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength');
rp.Radii = mean([rp.MajorAxisLength rp.MinorAxisLength],2) / 2;

rp([rp.Eccentricity] > 0.75,:) = [];
rp(rp.EquivDiameter < 10 | rp.EquivDiameter > 30,:) = [];

imshow(img);
hold on;
viscircles(rp.Centroid,rp.Radii);
hold off;
```

The output is far from being the desired one, but I feel it's an improvement over your first trial:

[image: Output]

But I think that you can obtain the desired result by finding the right algorithm to adjust the radii and by tweaking the criterions to exclude unwanted regions.

Comment: how can it get the identified circle count?

Comment: Just use: numel(rp)

Comment: the other answer gives better results after changing sensitivity to 0.98. I apologize for unaccepting your answer. And i really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not a problem, as I said, this is beyond my domain of knowledge.